# React-Native Requiring unknown module "./lib/templates/bootstrap"

Tags: npm, react-native

I just started working with React Native. Now I am trying to get my client running however I'm facing this issue

```
Requiring unknown module "./lib/templates/bootstrap".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^2.10.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.37.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.5.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "17.0.0",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2"
  }
}
```

Then I tried to search the text `/lib/templates/bootstrap` in my project and I found it in `index.android.bundle`.

*module.exports=LoginView;
}, "client/views/LoginView.js");
__d(559 /* tcomb-form-native/index.js */, function(global, require, module, exports) {var _lib=require(560 /* ./lib */);var _lib2=babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault(_lib);
var _en=require(620 /* ./lib/i18n/en */);var _en2=babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault(_en);
**var _bootstrap=require('./lib/templates/bootstrap')**;var _bootstrap2=babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault(_bootstrap);
var _bootstrap3=require(621 /* ./lib/stylesheets/bootstrap */);var _bootstrap4=babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault(_bootstrap3);*

Anyone can shed some lights on this ?

Comment: Are you sure the path resolves properly?

Comment: I just updated the log. I can't seem to find the path in my project. Where does it should exist?

Comment: It should be in `lib/templates/bootstrap`, relative to whatever file is requiring it.

Comment: Okay I think I got it. It should be under `tcomb-form-native` however its not there. I'll try to reinstall or use diff version. Many Thanks.